# How to use a Sainsmart 8 Channel USB relay with python

Tags: python, relay

I've been looking for a couple hours now and I would like to get my Sainsmart 8 channel usb relay working using python. If anyone can help me out with this that would be fabulous. Thanks.

Comment: Please share what you have done so far.

Comment: While we're waiting for that: I hope you're not switching anything potentially hazardous with this. If I read "When the board is connected to the PC and the PC is restarted, the relays will be toggled several times. This is because of the structure of the FTDI chip." (https://www.sainsmart.com/products/8-channel-12v-usb-relay-module).. that could have disastrous consequences if you were switching something hazardous unexpectedly.

Comment: Hey, nothing was connected to the relay while I was testing. Most of my testing so far has been serial writes to it, in an attempt that failed. ser.write({255, 1, 1}) that’s an example. I’ve mostly been fiddling around with that. There are no errors in the python code, just nothing turns on

Answer (score 2):

So, there are two methods here, and it depends on where you want to go.  A) you could get a command line version working like usbrelay and then issue commands from python, and B) you could open up a serial connection from inside python and use usb.core or usb.util to send serial commands to the board.

A) Darrylb's work on github is nice overview here to get a command line tool working for HID Compatible Relays.   https://github.com/darrylb123/usbrelay

If you are on debian:

```
sudo apt-get install usbrelay
```

Then you update your rules.d file so you don't have to use 'sudo' all the time and  you can call the command line within python.  This has certain security implications of course, which you should google around for if you plan to use this longer term.

Anyway, once you get it installed, you can just call it from the command line and it will list your relay_ids in some format with suffixes that look like _1 through _8.

```
$ ./usbrelay
```

The output will show you info on the board you have attached, and give you the relay ids and the status.  A "1" is on and a "0" is off.

then from within python:

```
import os    
os.system("usbrelay 5291D_1=1 5291D_3=1")
```

To turn those off you just change the ones in the assignments to zeros, and you can do all eight relay numbers simultaneously.  So you could go on from there to write all kinds of functions to fire your relays in unique combinations, delays, etc.  You can also use subprocess from within python:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['usbrelay', '5291D_1=1', '5291D_3=1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

B) To take the serial connection approach, you have to start with knowing what the proper serial commands to your board is.  For example, I have a sainsmart 16-channel relay that requires me to send the serial commands because it isn't HID compatible.

Find your model number here on the Sainsmart Wiki: 
http://wiki.sainsmart.com/index.php/SKU

Then download the zip file and take a look at the relay instructions. For me, I used a modification of RJ's work to send a serial command.
https://gist.github.com/RJ/7acba5b06a03c9b521601e08d0327d56

This is from the instructions for my SKU number (Likely diff than yours!)
CH-6 ON 3A 46 45 30 35 30 30 30 35 46 46 30 30 46 39 0D 0A

You need to add a 0x prefix to the serial messages:

```
c6_on=[0x3A, 0x46, 0x45, 0x30, 0x35, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x35, 0x46, 0x46, 0x30, 0x30, 0x46, 0x39, 0x0D, 0x0A]
```

Then you can send those commands to the usb.core.Endpoint using an approach how RJ approached it in the git gist link above, with 'ep' here being the usb.core.Endpoint:

```
ep.write(c6_on)
```

Either way, as long as you can either A) control the board from the command line or B) know the right serial commands to send, then you can figure out how to do it with python.  The only other thing to watch out for is making sure you have the proper dependencies in place and watching permissions.

Answer (score 1):

after you have installed the USB driver (the executable from http://wiki.sainsmart.com/index.php/101-70-116) the following code will work to turn on first three relays. Each bit in the third number corresponds to an individual relay and needs to be turned on or off. My test was done on a windows 10 machine and is a result of trial and error. the documentation was not helpful.

e.g. If I passed [255,1,2], it will turn on second relay but turn off the first since second bit is on but all other bits are off.

> ```
> import serial
> import time
>
> serialPort = serial.Serial(port="COM6", baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, timeout=2, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
> elements=[255,1,1] 
> result = serialPort.write(elements) 
> time.sleep(2)
> elements=[255,1,3] 
> result = serialPort.write(elements) 
> time.sleep(2)
> elements=[255,1,7] 
> result = serialPort.write(elements) 
> serialPort.close()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As this module uses FT245RL USB FIFO integrated circuit, you can use this repo 
https://github.com/vpatron/relay_ft245r from Vince Patron.

the test.py source is quite easy and understandable :

```
import relay_ft245r
import sys
import time

rb = relay_ft245r.FT245R()
dev_list = rb.list_dev()

# list of FT245R devices are returned
if len(dev_list) == 0:
    print('No FT245R devices found')
    sys.exit()

# Show their serial numbers
for dev in dev_list:
    print(dev.serial_number)

# Pick the first one for simplicity
dev = dev_list[0]
print('Using device with serial number ' + str(dev.serial_number))

# Connect and turn on relay 2 and 4, and turn off
rb.connect(dev)
rb.switchon(2)    
rb.switchon(4)
time.sleep(1.0)
rb.switchoff(2)    
time.sleep(1.0)
rb.switchoff(4)
```